# Kotest beforeTest can not connect to database in a MicronautTest

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I created a Kotest StringSpec test in a Micronaut project, and tried to clear data in the database.

```kotlin
@MicronautTest(environments = [Environment.TEST], startApplication = false)
class PostRepositoryTest(private val posts: PostRepository, private val template: JdbcOperations) : StringSpec({
   "a test" {//test includes database operations worked well.
    }
}){
    override fun beforeEach(testCase: TestCase) {
       val delCount = this.template.prepareStatement("delete from posts") { it ->
            it.executeUpdate()
       }
       print("deleting items: $delCount")
  }

}
```

The `this.template.prepareStatement` statement failed due to an exception of can not get a database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the beforeTest hook into a transaction to make it.

Inject a `TransactionOperatoions` in the constructor of  `PostRepositoryTest`

Then call the deletion in a callback.

```kotlin
override fun beforeEach(testCase: TestCase) {
        val callback: TransactionCallback<Any, Int> = TransactionCallback { _: TransactionStatus<Any> ->
            val sql = "delete from posts";
            this.template.prepareStatement(sql) {
                it.executeUpdate()
            }
        }

        val cnt = tx.executeWrite(callback)
        println("deleted $cnt");
    }
```